# How to reach SelectedItem in nested ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I'm wrestling with these last few days. I found lots of links, but none of them really helped me. I'm quite a beginner in WPF.
 All I need is to reach SelectedItem property in nested ListView.
 Outter ListView binding works, of course.
What I tried after some research and doesn't work, even I don't really understand why it dosnt work:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewRef.View.ListViewWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ListViewRef.ViewModel"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewRef.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Nested List Views" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel x:Name="Global">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MainTitle}"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=OutterSelectedItem}"
                  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Now second ListView:"/>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=NestedSelectedItem,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=vm:MainVM},
                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  ></ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And ViewModel:

```
using ListViewRef.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace ListViewRef.ViewModel
{
    public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string mainTitle;

        public string MainTitle {
            get { return mainTitle; }
            set { mainTitle = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainTitle)); }
        }

        private string nestedSelectedItem;

        public string NestedSelectedItem {
            get { return nestedSelectedItem; }
            set 
            {
                nestedSelectedItem = value;
                MessageBox.Show("NestedSelectedItem: " + nestedSelectedItem);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NestedSelectedItem)); 
            }
        }

        private string outterSelectedItem;

        public string OutterSelectedItem {
            get { return outterSelectedItem; }
            set 
            {
                outterSelectedItem = value;
                MessageBox.Show("OutterSelectedItem: " + OutterSelectedItem);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OutterSelectedItem)); 
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ClassWithObsList> SourceCollection { get; set; }

        public MainVM()
        {
            MainTitle = "Title of the Grid";

            SourceCollection = new ObservableCollection<ClassWithObsList> {
                new ClassWithObsList("First Title", new ObservableCollection<string> { "First", "Second"}),
                new ClassWithObsList("Second Title", new ObservableCollection<string> { "Third", "Fourth"}),
                new ClassWithObsList("Third Title", new ObservableCollection<string> { "Fifth", "Sixth"}),
            };
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ListViewRef.Model
{
    public class ClassWithObsList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string title;

        public string Title {
            get { return title; }
            set {
                title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ClassWithObsList(string title, ObservableCollection<string> strings)
        {
            Title = title ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(title));
            Strings = strings ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(strings));
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=NestedSelectedItem,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=vm:MainVM}, ...}
```

the type `vm:MainVM` is not an ancestor type of the inner ListView, because it not part of a visual or logical tree.

The AncestorType must be a UI element, e.g. the outer ListView. You would access the property by a nested property Path via its DataContext:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.NestedSelectedItem,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, ...}
```

---

As a note, since you are not setting the `View` property of the ListViews, you could as well use the simpler base class ListBox instead of ListView:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceCollection}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=OutterSelectedItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Now second ListView:"/>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.NestedSelectedItem,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox},
                             Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help and explanation, this solved the problem. Do I understand it now right, that RelativeSource sets what DataContext of What UI Element I want to bind to?

Comment: Not exactly "what DataContext", but the source object of the Binding. The source is set by either the Source, RelativeSource or ElementName properties of the Binding, or if none of these is set, the DataContext of the target element. The value of the DataContext property is inherited by child elements from their parent element, that's why the ListView's DataContext is that of the Window.

Comment: I see err in my deduction. Thank you very much, Clemens. It's been very helpful.